# Custom Collectionview under each tableview rows

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode7

I am new in objective c. I want to create a layout design like android app store. Which means, i have a tableview and each row of tableview has a collectionview, and one more thing, i am using xcode7 and i want to create a design with storyboard. When i should create a that type of design each tableview row show collectionview but my problem is that each collectionview have save data. but i want to different data in every row. I go throw many tutorial but i can't understand. Can anyone assist me, how to create that type of design? Now i am create a tableview datasourse and delegate method in viewcontroller.m file and also use collection view's datasourse and delegate method into custom tableview cells.m class. please any one assist me

Answer (score 0):

> each collectionview have save data. but i want to different data in every row

because your collection view's datasourse and delegate method in tableViewCell is same.maybe it's not ok to determine dataSource and delegate implementation in tableViewCell ,you can delegate it out to your ViewController, and each tableViewCell's has different  implementation.

I have try to implementation a demo , it can work ,but i think may have better way. this is my code

Cell.h

```
//Cell.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MTTableViewCell;
@protocol MTTableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section     InTableViewCell:(MTTableViewCell *)cell;
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(    NSIndexPath *)indexPath InTableViewCell:(MTTableViewCell *)cell;

@end

@interface MTTableViewCell : UITableViewCell<UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MTTableViewCellDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UICollectionView *collectionView;

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger index; // [tablview indexPathForCell:] not work before cell is render

@end
```

Cell.m

```
//Cell.m
#import "MTTableViewCell.h"

@interface MTTableViewCell()

@end

@implementation MTTableViewCell


- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds collectionViewLayout:layout];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - 

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(    collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:InTableViewCell:)]) {
        return [_delegate collectionView:collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section InTableViewCell:self];
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(    NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(    collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:InTableViewCell:)]) {
        return [_delegate collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath     InTableViewCell:self];
    }
    return nil;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)    collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(50, 50);
}

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MTTableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,MTTableViewCellDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;

    _tableView.rowHeight = 72.0;

    [self.view addSubview:_tableView];


}
#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource & UITableViewDelegate

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MTTableViewCell *cell = (MTTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[MTTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    cell.index = indexPath.row;
    cell.delegate = self;
    [cell.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CCell"];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(    NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MTTableViewCell *mtCell = (MTTableViewCell *)cell;
    if (!mtCell.collectionView.superview) {
        [mtCell addSubview:mtCell.collectionView];
        mtCell.collectionView.delegate = mtCell;
        mtCell.collectionView.dataSource = mtCell;
    }
}

#pragma mark - MTTableViewCellDelegate

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(    NSIndexPath *)indexPath InTableViewCell:(MTTableViewCell *)cell {
    UICollectionViewCell *cCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CCell"     forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return cCell;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section     InTableViewCell:(MTTableViewCell *)cell {

    [_tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    return cell.index
    ;
}

@end
```

Hope this can help you :)

Comment: I think your way is right. But where i can create a collectionview design. ur protocol idea is right. Can u explane more

Comment: hi Abhinaba~  you may notice i have set collectionView 's delegate and dataSource in `- tableView: willDisplayCell: forRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method, because each collectionView is related to each tableViewCell, so we need tableViewCell is already for use(related delegate and dataSource method is called by System). and i just have tried, you can update ur collectionview's design in this method too. :)